# Setting the date time format to multiple columns of a dataframe at once Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in my DataFrame which I format to a specific time format.  It works with two lines of code below but I want to combine into one command

```
df['Time01'] = pd.to_datetime(Time_01).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['Time02'] = pd.to_datetime(Time_02).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

I have tried the following

```
df[['Time_01','Time_02']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%H:%M:%S')
```

But get the following error message

> None of [Index(['Time_01', 'Time_02'], dtype='object')] are in the
> [columns]

New python and pandas any help appreciated

Comment: what exactly are `Time_01` and `Time_01`? are they lists? are they dataframe columns? In your working examples, you are using the `Time_01` and `Time_02` objects as the arguments for `pd.to_datetime`, but we don't see where those objects are defined. In the example that doesn't work, the error message is saying the columns don't exist. Are you trying to set new columns named `'Time_01` and `Time_02` or are you trying to pass existing columns with those names to the function? what you are doing is passing columns of those names

Comment: I was picking this up from something already  written at closer inspection they are lists, your comment helped me realize that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proposed solution doesn't work because as the error says, there are no columns `"Time_01"` and `"Time_02"` yet in `df` and `Time_01` and `Time_02` that are converted to pandas datetime objects are objects independent of `df`. One way to write the first two lines into a single line is to write it in a dict comprehension and pass the resulting dictionary to the `assign` method:

```
df = df.assign(**{f'Time0{i+1}': pd.to_datetime(lst).strftime('%H:%M:%S') 
                  for i, lst in enumerate((Time_01, Time_02))})
```